# XSL apply-templates with sorting does not sort

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have an XML document

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <timeperiods>
        <timeperiod>
            <day>1</day>
            <period>1</period>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod>
            <day>1</day>
            <period>2</period>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod>
            <day>2</day>
            <period>1</period>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod>
            <day>2</day>
            <period>2</period>
        </timeperiod>
    </timeperiods>
</document>
```

I am applying an XSL as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/document/timeperiods">
            <xsl:sort select="number(period)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(day)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="timeperiod">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(period, '-', day, ' ')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect that my template `timeperiod` would result in `1-1 1-2 2-1 2-2`, but instead it results in `1-1 2-1 1-2 2-2`, which is the original order in the XML file.

I played around with the `number()` function and the attributes `data-type` and `order`, but no matter which variant I applied, I am always getting the same result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. I am guessing you want to sort the `timeperiod` elements, not the (single) `timeperiods` element - so you should do `<xsl:apply-templates select="timeperiod">` (from the right context, of course).

Comment: I provided the MRE - sorry for missing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a result like the one you expect, change:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/document/timeperiods">
        <xsl:sort select="number(period)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="number(day)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

to:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/document/timeperiods/timeperiod">
        <xsl:sort select="period" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="day" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

---

Or do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/document">
    <xsl:for-each select="timeperiods/timeperiod">
        <xsl:sort select="period" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="day" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="period, day" separator="-"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is only one element named `timeperiods`, and sorting a sequence of length one is not going to be useful.

You want to sort the `timeperiod` elements, so those are the ones you should select. You haven't given the context of the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction; obviously that will affect how you select them.

Comment: I thought that the sorting is applied to the element and all its children. So, if I got you right, I should call `xsl:apply-templates` on `/document/timeperiods/timeperiod` and the sorting will take effect?

Comment: Sorting is applied to the set of nodes selected by the select attribute. You want to sort `timeperiod` elements, so you need to select `timeperiod` elements.